# pass value from post back to get with RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC - 'Index' functions loads page, values are past back to 'IndexPost', updates are made and at the end of the post the index is reloaded.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

If the event updates are made in the post I would like to make changes in the original 'index' function to do this need to pass a value from the post to the get....
something like

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", userId);
```

then in the original get:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? userId)
```

How can this be done?
thank ye

Comment: You can put the value in `TempData` and retrieve it in the IndexGet

Comment: please stop putting incorrect tags on your post.

Comment: -1 It is not too hard to read all overloads method has: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question you have to use

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { userId = userId } );
```